# Select text of IText on FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I want set the text selection by code in FabricJS like the image. When I create the IText object I need to select all text to facilitate the editing.

I check the documentation, but no success.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it in [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html#selectAll). And prepared use example for you

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { fabric } from "fabric";

const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c", { width: 600, height: 600 });

const iText = new fabric.IText("Hello world!");

canvas.setActiveObject(iText);
iText.enterEditing();
iText.selectAll();
canvas.add(iText);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/fabricjs-playground-forked-jl0ui?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Its not editable till i click on it. is there any way to make is editable

Comment: just remove line `iText.selectAll();` from the example. Is it what you want?

Comment: On toushscreen devices (mobile / iPad) etc i want to show keyboard and if user edit text it should start editing.